# Where can I buy .ar domain names?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar

I am having trouble finding a registrar that allows the purchase of one-off .ar domains.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot register a .AR domain directly. .COM.AR are open to everyone, though a local presence is required. Gandi will provide this to you if needed. During the registration process, you need to specify you ID number. For individuals, this may be your passport number, your national ID, or drivers' license number. Companies and organizations can provide their tax ID or VAT number.

Via - https://www.gandi.net/domaine/ar/info?lang=en